# Is incrementing of current value while putting thread-safe in ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

I wonder what happens when I modify current value while putting it into `ConcurrentHashMap`.

I have `ConcurrentHashMap` (`ConncurentHashMap<String, Integer> attendance`) with existing mapping of conference hall names and number of visitors to each.

Every invocation of `visit(conferenceHallName)` method is supposed to increment the number of visitors to the given conference hall. Every invoker is a thread.

So here is the method:

```
public void visit(String conferenceHallName) {    
   attendance.put(conferenceHallName, attendance.get(conferenceHallName) + 1);    
}
```

`put()` is locking method, `get()` is not. But what happens first in this case:

1. thread will lock segment with this mapping, then calculate a new value and then put and release which is perfect for me
   or
2. thread will get the old value, calculate a new one, then lock segment and put which means inconsistency for me and I will need to find a workaround.

And if the second scenario is what happens in reality will using `AtomicInteger` instead of `Integer` solve my issue?

Comment: If you are using Java 8, you can get the correct behavior with `attendance.merge(conferenceHallName, 1, Integer::sum)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second description is closer to what actually happens: the thread will access the value in a thread-safe way, construct a new `Integer` with the updated count, then lock the map, and replace the object.

Using `AtomicInteger` instead of `Integer` will solve the issue:

```
attendance.get(conferenceHallName).getAndIncrement();
```

This is assuming that all `conferenceHallName` keys are properly set in the map.